# Convert params correspond to function arguments

Tags: php

#### arg.php

```
<?php

include 'libs/Arg.php';

$method = 'test';
$params = $_REQUEST;

$arg = new Arg;
$arg->{$method}($params);
```

#### libs/Arg.php

```
<?php

class Arg
{
    public function test($arguments)
    {
        extract($arguments);
        echo $name;
        echo $age;
    }
}
```

I want to use arg.php as ajax adapter, call class function by method name, but in the function `$arguments` will be ambiguous, can I convert the params and make it correspond to the function arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it with the help of

```
call_user_func_array()
```

for example if you have the arguments name and age then you can write functions like this

```
      public function test($name,$age) {
      }
```

### arg.php

```
include 'libs/Arg.php';
$method = 'test';
$params = $_REQUEST;

$arg = new Arg;
call_user_func_array(array($arg,$method), $params);
```

### libs/Arg.php

```
class Arg
{
    public function test($name,$age)
    {
        echo $name;
        echo $age;
    }
}
```

So you don't need to use $arguments and extract it. As you mentioned in your post it is ambiguous. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Passing arguments by *position* can easily be done using [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array).

If you want to match names to names, you'll need to use some [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php):

```
$method = 'test';
$params = $_REQUEST;

$obj = new Arg;
$ref = new ReflectionMethod($obj, $method);

$arguments = array_map(
    function (ReflectionParameter $param) use ($params) {
        if (isset($params[$param->getName()])) {
            return $params[$param->getName()];
        }
        if ($param->isOptional()) {
            return $param->getDefaultValue();
        }
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Missing parameter ' . $param->getName());
    },
    $ref->getParameters()
);

$ref->invokeArgs($obj, $arguments);
```